# Google Script IFS condition

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

Can Someone help me to convert this Google Sheet formula to script?

I need to compare Column A and B and then i need to get answer in C Column

`=IFS(AND(A2="Fruit,",B2="Apple"),"OK",AND(A2="Fruit,",B2="Orange"),"OK",A2<>"Fruit","NOK")`

Comment: Why do you need a script? You are not giving context or show what you have done yourself.

Comment: [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Comment: Hello Marios, 
NOK function is not working. 
Can you please support me on this condition please?

If A="Good" and B="5star" then C="OK"    
 If A="Fair" and B="5star" then C="OK"     
 If A!="Fair" or A!= "Good" and B="1star" then C="OK"   
 all other cases should be "NOK"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Explanation:

It is basically [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65381812/11225291) answer with a few tweaks/improvements. This is just the recommended way to do it:

1. According to [best practices](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/support/best-practices) avoid executing `getRange/setValue` within a loop.
2. You can definitely use a `for` loop to accomplish 1), although [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) is faster, requires less variables and overall it is more efficient.
3. The [getLastRow](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getlastrow) method ensures that you are not iterating over empty cells (after last row with content).
4. I prefer to use a [ternary operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator) for cases like this one because it makes your code smaller and more manageable. But this step is optional.

Finally, I think you want `Fruit,` instead of `Fruit` but feel free to change that part in the code below.

### Solution:

```
function compair(){
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  const sh = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet1");
  const vals = sh.getRange("A2:B"+sh.getLastRow()).getValues();
  const fvals=vals.map(r=>[r[0]=="Fruit," && ["Apple","Orange"].includes(r[1])?"OK":"NOK"]);
  sh.getRange(2,3,fvals.length,1).setValues(fvals);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Never the les... Should be someting like this:

```
function compair(){
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  const sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Data");
  const values = sheet.getRange("A2:B").getValues();
  
  for (var i = 0; i < values.length; i++){
    if (values[i][0] == "Fruit" && values[i][1] == "Apple" || values[i][1] == "Orange"){
      sheet.getRange(i + 2, 3).setValue("OK");
    } else {
      sheet.getRange(i + 2, 3).setValue("NOK");
    }
  }
}
```